# Assignment operator overload

Tags: c++

I have class that has assignment to `string` operator.

```
class turbo
    {
public:
    operator string   (void) {printf("assignment to string operator\n");return "bla2";}
    };
```

Assignment operation works just fine:

```
turbo t;
string s;
s=t;
```

And I have `"assignment to string operator"` in output.

Then I decided to make another assignment operator to `turbo`

```
class turbo
    {
public:
    operator string   (void) {printf("assignment to string operator\n");return "bla";}
    operator turbo   (void) {printf("assignment to turbo operator\n");return *this;}
    };
```

But code below does not calls `turbo` assignment operator.

```
turbo t;
turbo tt ;
tt=t;
```

Why?

I know that I can overload `=` operator, but I expect operator `turbo` work also since `string` one is operating.

Comment: These are not assignment operators - they're conversion operators.

Comment: Like said in an above comment, the operators are *conversion* operators. And there's no use in converting a type to the same type, is there? Read more about [user-defined conversion operators here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). If you want have custom copy-assignment then you have to overload the `=` operator (related reading: [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).

Answer (score 2):

You are not overloading assignment operators, but conversion operators. So they are called when conversion takes place.

See [c++: cast operator vs. assign operator vs. conversion constructor priority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12335684)

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are _conversion_ operators, and are called when conversions take place (which might be due to casts, but can also happen implicitly without any cast)

Answer (score 1):

The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator of a class takes a single parameter of type `X const&` (here `turbo const&`). Since your RHS operand is already of type `turbo`, there is no need to call the conversion function.

Indeed, a conversion function to the same type is never called implicitly; it can only be called explicitly (as `turbo::operator turbo()`) or possibly via a virtual conversion function in a base class.  This is discussed in **[class.conv.fct]**:

> 1 - [...]  A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void. [...]

See [Under what circumstances would a type's conversion operator to itself be invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350678/under-what-circumstances-would-a-types-conversion-operator-to-itself-be-invoked)