# Weird warning with SFINAE conversion function

Tags: c++, g++, clang

This is my sample code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <bool B>
struct S {
    // #1
    // template <bool C = B, class = std::enable_if_t<!C>>
    // operator S<true>() const { return {}; }

    // #2
    // operator S<true>() const { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    S<true> b1;
    S<false> b2;
}
```

When compiling with g++ (https://godbolt.org/z/P46qE8EGG) I get no warning whether I enable option #1, option #2, or both. I would expect a warning that it is a self conversion function when I enable #2, but maybe g++ doesn't have such a warning.

The real issue is when compiling with clang. I get the following warnings only if I enable #1:

> error: conversion function converting 'S' to itself will never be used [-Werror,-Wclass-conversion]

Enabling #2 does not trigger this warning, and disabling the instantiation of either `b1` or `b2` does not prevent it. What is going on? Is this an error in clang?

**EDIT:**  I am referring specifically to why #1 produces the warning. The other info was meant to show my attempts at trying to narrow the problem to a smaller working example

Comment: Dupe/related: [Under what circumstances would a type's conversion operator to itself be invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350678/under-what-circumstances-would-a-types-conversion-operator-to-itself-be-invoked)

Comment: [A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351375/12002570)

Comment: @user12002570 I don't think this is a dupe, it is a corner case of a conversion function that _may_ be used but which clang erroneously flags as "will never be used". In both cases of interest it is not conversion to self, but conversion from `S<false>` to `S<true>`. Clang diagnostic bug. I would vote for re-opening.

Comment: @dfrib I agree, you can reopen

Comment: Does `template <bool C = B, class = std::enable_if_t<!C>>` `operator S<!C>() const { return {}; }` do what you want without producing warnings? Or perhaps: `template <bool C = B>` `operator std::enable_if_t<!C, S<!C>>() const { return {}; }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo the second one works, and is preferable anyway. Default parameters are not a good place to exercise SFINAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would expect a warning that it is a self conversion function when I enable #2, but maybe g++ doesn't have such a warning.

Correct, one can hope for compiler warnings (non-standard best practices), but there is no guarantee that a certain compiler provides them.

> Enabling #2 does not trigger this warning, and disabling the instantiation of either b1 or b2 does not prevent it. What is going on? Is this an error in clang?

Clang is correct to not warn for `#2`, as it may be invoked, shown easier in an example with deleted definitions:

```
template <bool B>
struct S {  
    // #2
    operator S<true>() const = delete;
};

int main() {
    S<false> const b1;
    S<true> b2 = b1;  // error: call to a deleted function
}
```

Why? Since the implicit copy constructor copies

```
S<true>  -> S<true>
S<false> -> S<false>
```

whereas however `S<false>` into `S<true>` is not a copy operation in the same sense.

The template constructor is also present when the "copy from" class is `S<false>`, so Clang may seem to, at first glance, to incorrectly warn that this function will never be used:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool B>
struct S {
    // #1 - warning: -Wclass-conversion
    template <bool C = B, class = std::enable_if_t<!C>>
    operator S<true>() const = delete;
};

int main() {
    S<false> const b1;
    S<true> b2 = b1;  // error: deleted function
}
```

However, Clang is likely not smart enough to analyze the SFINAE, and we can see the SFINAE construct is a red herring for when or when not the warning is emitted, as we get the same diagnostic in the following case:

```
template <bool B>
struct S {
    // #1 - warning: -Wclass-conversion
    template <typename Dummy = void>
    operator S<true>() const = delete;
};

int main() {
    S<false> const b1;
    S<true> b2 = b1;  // error: deleted function
}
```

We realize that Clang emits the warnings for when we instantiate `S<true>`, for which case it is actually true: the function will never be invoked.

```
template <bool B>
struct S {
    // #1
    template <typename Dummy = void>
    operator S<true>() const = delete;
};

S<false> sf{}; // correct: no warning emitted for #1
S<true>  st{}; // correct: warning emitted for #1
```

At this point we may wonder why then it doesn't emit a warning for `#1`. It could be that a template function (`#1`) ranks one step lower in overload resolution, or that analysis of the non-dependent non-template function (`#2`) happens only once, independent of enclosing the class template specializations' instantiations.

If we make sure the function is never converting-to-self for any instantiation, the warnings, as expected, disappears:

```
template <bool B>
struct S {
    // #1
    template <typename Dummy = void>
    operator S<!B>() const = delete;
};

S<false> sf{}; // no warning emitted for #1
S<true>  st{}; // no warning emitted for #1
```

I wouldn't be surprised if Clang rejected a bug report for this issue, as the warning is accurate for the specialization which it flags it for, unless some heroic effort would go into understanding when and when not a certain template function is SFINAE:d or not.

Comment: Ok. But this still leaves the main question open. Why wont clang allow #1?

Comment: @Baruch I posted my answer mid-answering as I feared someone would dupe-close the question given the comments, and time would've been wasted on writing an answer that couldn't be posted. I've now completed the answer: Clang is wrong to flag #1 as never to be used.

Comment: as as indeed happened...

Comment: @Baruch I've kind of changed my mind, and think Clang is correct, to as far as we expect (Clang not doing heroic effort to understand SFINAE results): updated the answer accordingly. If anything, I think it's confusing that it (like GCC) doesn't emit the warnings for the non-template case `#2`, but it could be that that function is analyzed independently of class specialization, as it is not dependent on a template parameter of the enclosing class template, not a function template itself (the latter would mean delayed instantiation and analysis).